# Symfony yml - password with @

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony project, a have in parameters.yml a password like: '@string'
Unfortunately, I got an error:

```
The service has a dependency on a non-existent service "string".
```

The system probably thinks that after @ is a parameter.

What can I do to properly use the password?

Comment: Show your yaml file

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings

Comment: Thanks. It is helpfully

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony, use

```
'@my_service_name'
```

to fetch service and

```
'%my_parameter_name%'
```

to fetch parameter